# Windows 10 Froze At Automatic Repair At Boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, power-supply, freeze

Okay so this has had me scratching my head all day. My power supply literally went out with a bang (make a pop like a firecracker before shutting down) and I had it replaced with a bigger and better supply. Now when I boot my computer, it wants to do an automatic repair but freezes before it can do anything. I have a MSI motherboard and from my research, F11 gets into the Boot menu but when I try it, the computer freezes up at the MSI screen that shows when you first boot the computer up. It wont beep on start up or anything when I spam F11. Ive tried other random F hotkeys with no luck. HELP! I would give a list of my hardware but I didn't build this computer and its still relatively new to me.The brand name is iBuyPower with windows 10 Pro on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your PSU (Power Supply Unit) probably fried your motherboard. Try pressing F2 or DEL to get into the BIOS. If this succeeds, your motherboard is still operating fine, and Windows is damaged.

Try changing the boot order, and boot from a USB or CD/DVD. If this succeeds you can try installing Windows.

Comment: I'm honestly thinking my motherboard is fried as well. I tried both and F2 did nothing, DEL froze it up at the MSI boot up screen like F11 did.

Answer (score 0):

My first gut instinct leans towards the "That does not sound good..." side, but I'll start off optimistic.

Have you tried both the DEL and delete buttons as well during the boot proces ?
Sometimes pressing ESC with MSI during the boot process will reveal text messages and could give a hint toward a problem. There is loads of debug advise I could give but the fact that you are not even getting passed BIOS boot (MSI logo) gives me the impression that some of the internal parts might be messed up.

My next advise would include perhaps removing some parts ( removing 1 ram stick or the dedicated video card for example ). But I would not recommend it if you are not a bit of a hardware enthousiast being comfortable messing with the "internal organs" of a PC.

Otherwise I'm afraid it sounds like your motherboard's internal components might have gotten fried by the PSU (power supply unit) blowout. Generally this is a reason to use a good PSU from an established brand.